# need to get tf2_ros to work in python3 environment for Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need tf2 to work in python3 environment in ROS melodic. I saw a similar question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/326226/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit__tf2/?answer=399302#post-id-399302) for ROS kinetic, I need the same thing for melodic. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399303/need-to-get-tf2_ros-to-work-in-python3-environment-for-melodic/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Melodic the binary installation of ROS is built [against the python2 (REP 3)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025) version on the system.

If you want to use tf2_ros or any other python elements of ROS Melodic in python3 you need to build it from source in an environment where python3 is the default. We made the effort to test all packages up to desktop and they are generally expected to work with python3 in Melodic. Beyond that you may find packages that are not dual compatible.

You will have to modify the [source installation instructions](https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source) to setup python3 in your environment. Make sure to always be in the python3 environment when interacting with that installation. You will also have to install all the python depeendencies into your python3 environment manually, and the rosdeps on melodic will install the python2 dependencies as that's what the default is for melodic.

If you move forward to noetic the default is python3 and you can use it there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-04-20**:
@tfoote is the solution provided in this similar [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/326226/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit__tf2/?answer=399302#post-id-399302) work for ros kinetic?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-04-20**:
There are lots of shortcuts that you can take if you know what you're doing. However I'll caution that if you try to do just part of it, you're going to run into issues trying to use python2 libraries which might be shared dependencies of potential downstream packages. You need to have python3 environments and python2 environments non-overlapping. It's really easy to shoot yourself in the foot. And if you're asking how to solve it here I would not recommend you try the more advanced ways or shortcuts.